# Installing npm sharp module on Ubuntu failed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, sharp

I faced issue while was trying to install sharp module on ubuntu server.
I tried to install it to my project folder but had no success there.
I had a guess that this might happen due to some conflicts with current modules. After that I tried to install it to the new folder with no modules in it, but result was the same.

The issue flow is next. I try to install sharp module, then it stuck in this state (I waited for around an hour and nothing changed).

```
(##################) ⠼ reify:sharp: timing reifyNode:node_modules/semver Completed in 145ms
```

After that I pressed ctrl+c and here is the error that I got

```
root@ubuntu-front:/var/tmp/tes# npm i sharp
npm ERR! path /var/tmp/tes/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGINT
npm ERR! command sh /tmp/install-4252fa98.sh
npm ERR! sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.13.2/libvips-8.13.2-linux-x64.tar.br

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-10-12T12_56_38_692Z-debug-0.log
```

And here is output from the dump file

```
288 info run sharp@0.31.1 install node_modules/sharp (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
289 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 275ms
290 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 278ms
291 silly audit report {}
292 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
293 timing reify:audit Completed in 279ms
294 info run sharp@0.31.1 install { code: null, signal: 'SIGINT' }
295 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 34ms
296 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
297 timing command:i Completed in 21196ms
298 verbose stack Error: command failed
298 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
298 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
298 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
298 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
299 verbose pkgid sharp@0.31.1
300 verbose cwd /var/tmp/tes
301 verbose Linux 5.15.0-48-generic
302 verbose node v16.17.0
303 verbose npm  v8.15.0
304 error path /var/tmp/tes/node_modules/sharp
305 error command failed
306 error signal SIGINT
307 error command sh /tmp/install-4252fa98.sh
308 error sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.13.2/libvips-8.13.2-linux-x64.tar.br
309 verbose exit 1
310 timing npm Completed in 21266ms
311 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1665579398761
312 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1665579400052
313 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1665579400052
314 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1665579400052
315 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1665579400057
316 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/sharp 1665579400057
317 verbose code 1
318 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
318 error     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-10-12T12_56_38_692Z-debug-0.log
```

I found some similar issues in the Internet but all of them were slightly different and suggested solutions didn't help in my case.

Here are the versions

```
# node -v
v16.17.0
# npm -v
8.15.0
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```